# JavaScript. Use Outlook online API from SharePoint online page without double user authorization

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, outlook

Is there any way to get user's events from Outlook online with JS from SharePoint online page without user re-authorization?

What API can be used?

User is already authorized on SharePoint Online, is it possible to somehow get autoriz token and use to query Outlook API?

Comment: Have you been able to figure out any work around for this problem?